# Google Translator, how to manually restore original language with javascript

Tags: html, css, google-translate

I am using google translate on my website. (https://translate.google.com/manager/website/suggestions)

Everything works as I want, but how do I manually (with javascript) restore the original language button ?

The idea is this: I got my pages in my languages, so if a user changes this manually (without google translate) I want to disable the actual translation of google translate.

is this possible ?

I checked the iframe that translates generates, but I didn't find an answer there.

with kind regards

Answer (score 9):

Try using this to restore original state:

```
function() {
  var iframe = document.getElementsByClassName('goog-te-banner-frame')[0];
  if(!iframe) return;

  var innerDoc = iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow.document;
  var restore_el = innerDoc.getElementsByTagName("button");

  for(var i = 0; i < restore_el.length; i++){
    if(restore_el[i].id.indexOf("restore") >= 0) {
      restore_el[i].click();
      var close_el = innerDoc.getElementsByClassName("goog-close-link");
      close_el[0].click();
      return;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This works perfectly. I was previously clearing the `googtrans` cookies & reloading the page, but it stopped working.

Comment: After resetting the language "in place", you may want to clear any left-over GoogleTranslate language hash from the URL.  (Not recommended if you use hashes in your app.)  `history.pushState("", document.title, window.location.pathname + window.location.search);`