# How to make an Reset button for Google translate

Tags: google-translate

i'm using Google translate on my site, with the option not to show te topribbon or be rdirected to Google translate when translating the page to to another language. Now if i choose to show the top ribbon then in this ribbon there is an Reset button to show original language, but now when i'm not showing this ribbon there is no way to show original language except to choose my language fron the dropdown list, but if i do this it will be a translation on a translation if you know what I mean? so some words will show wrong. So what i want is an Reset button that i can but in the code i use for the Google translate dropdown list:

```
<div id="google_translate_element"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
   function googleTranslateElementInit() {
      new google.translate.TranslateElement({pageLanguage: 'sv'}, 
                                            'google_translate_element');

      jQuery('.goog-logo-link').css('display', 'none');
      jQuery('.goog-te-gadget').css('font-size', '0');
   }
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit"></script>
<style type="text/css">
.goog-tooltip {
   display: none !important;
}
.goog-tooltip:hover {
   display: none !important;
}
.goog-text-highlight {
   background-color: transparent !important;
   border: none !important; 
   box-shadow: none !important;
}
iframe.goog-te-banner-frame {
   display: none !important;
}
body {
   position: static !important; top:0px !important;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Please take a look on this:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8330669/how-to-add-google-translate-link-that-triggers-translation

Answer (score 5):

Even though you styled the ribbon away, it is still present in the DOM.
You can use jQuery to fake a click on the (hidden) reset button:

```
jQuery('#\\:1\\.container').contents().find('#\\:1\\.restore').click();
```

Unfortunately I cannot demonstrate it with a Stack Snippet ('allow-same-origin' does not work when sandboxed), but this fiddle works:
https://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/239032/

Comment: I was about to say the same :)

Comment: having a bit of trouble implementing this but I think that's on my end in terms of how this jQuery works alongside the google translate JS. Anyway I will dig into this, thanks for the lead

Comment: Doesn't work in 2021

Comment: I used this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35349779/5710912